# Draw edges connecting vertexes (by id) on QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, line, plot

I've been trying to figure out how to draw edges connecting a series of geographical points. There are many solutions that I've thought of but none of them take any advantage of the QGIS tools.

Definition of the data:

```
| Id of the edge | Node 1 | Node 2 |
|----------------|--------|--------|
| 0              | 0      | 1      |
| 1              | 1      | 0      |
| 2              | 1      | 2      |
| 3              | 2      | 1      |
```

```
| node id | long              | lat               |
|---------|-------------------|-------------------|
| 0       | 2522489\.71731237 | 4249914\.95175153 |
| 1       | 2522487\.82559798 | 4249915\.68685739 |
| 2       | 2522487\.13384956 | 4249916\.33410079 |
| 3       | 2522482\.48054117 | 4249922\.47666207 |
```

To plot the lat and long is not an issue but I haven't managed to draw an edge.

Comment: Those don't look like lat/lon values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From the processing Toolbox choose "Points to Path" tool. You can set the order field containing the ID order for each line and group the lines by a certain field

You might need to create the points first to make it easier and set the order and the group. The group being the line ID

I hope this helps.